# How should I move funds out of my USD PayPal account to a EUR or GBP bank account?

Tags: paypal

I have about USD 6000 in a PayPal account. I want to get it out of there and into a EUR or GBP bank account, in a way that that will incur the least charges, and enjoy the most favourable exchange rates.

The PayPal account shows the USD balance as *Primary*, as you can see below:

[image]

However, although I have opened a TransferWise Borderless account as suggested in one of the answers below, I cannot appear to link it to this PayPal account. It seems that the only kind of bank account I can link the PayPal account to is one with a six-digit sort code and 8-digit account number, as used in British bank accounts.

It appears to me that I have a UK PayPal account with a USD primary balance, and no obvious way of getting the USD out except by converting it to GBP within PayPal - which I would rather not do, as the reates will be very unfavourable.

Comment: What's the point of redacting the first two digits? You already told us it's about $6000, and it seems pretty obvious that the leading digit is a 7 anyway.

Comment: It was fun to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a certain amount of difficulty, I was able to do this.

I created a Transferwise Borderless account as advised in [one of the answers](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/120899/94188).

I wasn't able to add this to the PayPal account myself; however I called PayPal customer service and after a fairly long call had the account linked.

After that I immediately transferred the funds from PayPal, and they arrived in the Transferwise account the next day.

I have read multiple warnings that PayPal will remove Transferwise and other online accounts that are linked to PayPal accounts, but that hasn't been the case so far for me.

Answer (score 2):

Theoritically, one can transfer money from their Paypal account to their linked Bank account.

*However*, if the linked bank account is not originally in US Dollar and "local" to paypal, you will be in dire disadvantage of paying hefty conversion rates.

Another way to avoid the hefty paypal conversion by using [transferwise, which you can transfer money from paypal to the native currency into the borderless account](https://www.icomparefx.com/how-to-send-money-from-paypal-to-transferwise/). Then later you can move the money to your desired  EUR or GBP bank account.  You will save 2%~3% compare to paypal exchange rates.